# raspberry pi 2 model b accessing gpio larger than 26

Tags: gpio

There are 54 gpio according to the bcm2835 spec, but the pinout only show gpios up to number 26, how do I access gpio larger than 26? Do they share physical pins with gpios smaller than 27 ?

Comment: You may want to check the [schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf)

Comment: And here's a breakdown of what the chip's [GPIO pins are doing](https://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs)

Answer (score 4):

Not all the GPIO are connected to the expansion header.  Basically you can get physical access to GPIO 0-27.  Some of the other GPIO are also available at various points on the circuit board (e.g. those used to communicate with the SD card) but it would be rash to use them without understanding the consequences.  Most will be used by the operating system for its own purposes.

An exception is the compute module which does give physical access to all the GPIO 0-53.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the pins are accessible.  Barring ripping up the board and accessing the chip directly, you can only use the ones that you already identified.